On Laravel livewire search checkbox remains checked
Suppose I have 4 users, and I have already selected the first user before starting the search. When I search for the second user, the correct username appears in the search list, but its checkbox is already checked, even though I haven't checked it.
<div class="flex justify-center items-center mt-2"
     x-data="{ query: '', isFocused: false, firstFocus: false }">
     <div class="bg-white border selectPeople p-2 rounded-lg">
         <div x-show="!(isFocused && query.length > 1)">
             <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 mt-2">Select all the people you would like in
                 your organisation
                 chart</p>
         </div>
         <div class="search-container flex items-center mt-2">
             <img class="search-icon h-4 w-auto" src="{{ asset('images/MagnifyingGlass.svg') }}"
                 alt="Search Icon">
             <input wire:model.live.debounce.500ms="searchPeople" type="text" x-model="query"
                 x-on:focus="isFocused = true; firstFocus = true;" x-on:blur="isFocused = false"
                 class="w-full bordermainBlue outline-none block border py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 rounded-lg placeholder:text-gray-500 sm:text-md sm:leading-6"
                 placeholder="Search">
         </div>
         <div class="searchBox flex justify-center flex-col items-center" x-show="!firstFocus">
             <img class="" src="{{ asset('images/Illustration.png') }}" alt="Search Icon">
             <p class="text-black text-base font-semibold">Start entering individuals’ names
             </p>
         </div>
         <!-- User list with checkboxes -->
         <ul class="mt-4 adddeduser space-y-6 border py-4"
             x-show="(isFocused && query.length > 1) || firstFocus">
             @foreach($users as $user)
                 <li class="flex justify-between" key="{{ $user->id }}">
                     <div class="flex items-center gap-2 pl-4">
                         <div
                             class="border rounded-full w-10 h-10 text-white flex justify-center items-center text-center bg-cyan-500">
                             {{ strtoupper(substr($user->forename, 0, 1)) . strtoupper(substr($user->surname, 0, 1)) }}
                         </div>
                         <div class="space-y-1">
                             <span
                                 class="text-sm font-semibold block">{{ $user->forename . " " . $user->surname}}</span>
                             <span
                                 class="text-xs text-gray-500 block">{{ $user->role->title ?? ''}}</span>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <input type="checkbox" wire:model="selectedUsers" value="{{ $user->id }}"
                         class="form-checkbox h-4 w-4 mr-4 checkbx transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                 </li>
             @endforeach
         </ul>
         <div class="flex justify-end mt-4">
             <!-- Submit the form when the button is clicked -->
             <button type="submit" class="p-2 rounded-lg">Continue</button>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>


In the @foreach you have specified a key attribute instead of wire:key.
Change key="{{ $user->id }}" with wire:key="{{ $user->id }}" to let understand Livewire which checkbox to display:
@foreach($users as $user)
   <li class="flex justify-between" wire:key="{{ $user->id }}">
   .....

Here the related documentation

As a suggestion, it is also possible to remove the query variable and therefore also the x-model="query" attribute, because the searchPeople variable of Livewire is accessible from javascript via the magic property $wire, for example:
x-show="(isFocused && query.length > 1) || firstFocus"

can be changed in:
x-show="(isFocused && $wire.searchPeople.length > 1) || firstFocus"

